# Firebase Functions: "Failed to get status of functions deployments"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am getting a very strange error when I attempt to deploy my firebase functions.

As a test to rule out my code, I deleted everything except the `require(firebase-functions);` statement in my `index.js` file and then tried to deploy, but I again received the same error message:

```
Error: Failed to get status of functions deployments.
```

It also prompts me to see my function log file, but there is nothing new or relevant outputted there. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Same here.. Not sure seems like something is wrong with firebase.

Comment: *firebaser here* Thanks for raising this issue everyone. Thanks to these reports, we've found and fixed the issue (that was caused by a change earlier today). For further updates, keep checking the status page for updates: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18003

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please be sure you have the right nodejs version. Also for any issue regarding firebase product, the status can be checked in this link:

https://status.firebase.google.com/

The above link will provide a status for each service.

When the issue gets solved, you can just deploy your functions again with a different name instead of deleting or just redeploy them.

**Edit:**

Currently in the link above the issue is listed there, there is currently Service Disruption.

Please check this:https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18003

to know when this issue will be solved as the firebase team has seen that there is a problem.

Answer (score 6):

*firebaser here*

There is an ongoing issue with deploying Cloud Functions through the Firebase CLI. To track its status, look a the [Firebase status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/18003).

**Update: the issue was fixed at 7:22 am PST.**

I just successfully deployed some of my own functions, which was failing earlier. Thanks for your reports and patience everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when there were no deployment issues mentioned on the status page.

It turned out that the project just needed to "Link a billing account".

This can be done via the *Billing* section on [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing).